# python count words in each row, and save in new column

Tags: python

New to python and started learning dealing with data, and having some troubles with it.

I have a data set (pandas), and in each row I have a sentence. I want to create a new column, that counts the words in the sentence (in each row).

If the sentence is: "Hello World Hello dogs", the word counter will be -

```
{'Hello' - 2, 'World' - 1, 'dogs' -1}
```

I usually use graphlab, and it is done there by:

```
dataset['new_column'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(..)
```

I saw plenty of similar solutions, but not on a data set when adding a new column, and I never really programmed in python.

Would love some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against storing dictionaries in cells in your dataframe, however if there is no way around it you could use `Counter`

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame([['Hello world dogs'], ['this is another sentence']], columns=['column_of_interest'] )

from collections import Counter
dataset['new_column'] = dataset.column_of_interest.apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(' ')))
dataset

    column_of_interest  new_column
0   Hello world dogs    {'dogs': 1, 'world': 1, 'Hello': 1}
1   this is another sentence    {'is': 1, 'sentence': 1, 'this': 1, 'another': 1}
```

**EDIT:** Based on the comment below if there are cells which do not contain strings you may need to convert to `str` before splitting `lambda x: Counter(str(x).split(' ')))`

Comment: I'm getting an error - "'float' object has not attribute 'split'", 
it works of course on your code, but on my csv file it doesn't

Comment: If you could edit your original question to include and example of what the data input should be, and what the output should be, it may be easier to trouble shoot. I'm afraid without seeing the data any suggestion I make would be a guess. With that said my guess is that there are rows which contain only numbers which will need to be converted to strings

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did the trick.

An answer without pandas if anybody wants:

```
def word_count(text):
    word_count = {}
    for word in text.split():
        if word not in word_count:
            word_count[word] = 1
        else:
            word_count[word] += 1
    return word_count

data['word_count'] = data['sentences'].apply(word_count)
```

testing:

```
print word_count("Hello Hello world")
```

output:

```
{'world': 1, 'Hello': 2}
```